# Having issue applying simple CSS to a jsp page

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat

I can not get a simple CSS to apply to my jsp page. The page displays, but just black on white (no underline).  The TOMCAT localhost_access_log shows the GET of the CSS is successful (200).

using Tomcat with directories:

- web-apps/myapp
  --jsp -- cat_list.jsp
  --css -- main.css
  --WEB-INF

main.css:

```
h3 {
    background-color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

cat_list.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Category List</title>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
        <h3> Test Text </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the path to `css/main.css` correct in relation to the path of the `jsp` page?

Comment: jsp and css are separate directories under the app directory -- and css was found by tomcat according to the localhost log

Comment: It is working now, though I don't understand why this caused the issue.  I have a servlet for this jsp (cat) and I have a separate servlet for a separate set of jsps (budget).  The cat servlet was set for url-pattern '/cat_list'.  Budget was set for url '/'.  Apparently, after running the cat servlet it also ran the budget servlet.  Using firefox/firebug - when I would click the main.css it would bring up the code from the budget jsp (wtf - not even in same directory).  Apparently, running the budget servlet loaded its jsp into the main.css content somehow.

Comment: The above should not work, unless there are URL mappings that you have not disclosed.

Comment: Agreed - however, as soon as I put something other than '/' into the budgetServlet supported urls (chg'd from '/' to '/budget'), all the CSS started working for the 'cat_list' url (and budget urls for that matter).  [btw - they are all under the same 'app' level url...localhost:8080/budget/<budget> or <cat_list>].

Comment: Path issue: change your path to /css/main.css and try again.